# AWS JAR file won't build in target folder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is probably a really stupid question...

I've taken over a role from someone and I've been roughly following their structure and set up for an AWS Lambda function.

I have created a handler class, controller, service, etc and the application starts with no issues.

My problem is that an aws.jar file does not appear in the target folder and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

My template.yaml file looks like this:

`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Description is here`

`Resources:
  UpdateUserProfileFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: com.company.lambda.userprofile.updater.handler.aws.UpdateUserProfileRequestHandler
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/company-lambda-user-profile-updater-201810-8-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 60`

Which mirrors the set up for the application that does have an aws jar in its target.

The handler looks like this:

`package com.company.lambda.userprofile.updater.handler.aws;`

`import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler;`

`public class UpdateUserProfileRequestHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<ScheduledEvent, String> {}`

Any advice at all would be appreciated as I'm new to this sort of stuff!

Comment: Do you have `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` in your project directory? If yes, then you can try `mvn clean install` or `gradlew build` respectively. PS: you should have maven installed to execute `mvn` command. If your project has gradle wrapper, then no need to install `gradle`.

Comment: Thanks Rishikesh, I do have maven and I have ran mvn clean install. In the pom file, I also have a dependence on aws-lambda-java-core, aws-lambda-java-events and spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws

Comment: Correct `mvn clean install` will fetch all the dependencies available from maven central repository. If above mentioned dependencies are your local java project, then you can execute `mvn clean install` to get those installed in your local maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`). Once all your dependencies are resolved, you should be able to build your project. After building the project, under `target` directory you should be able to see the jar file.

Comment: Could you please share your pom file?